# Android account settings crashes

Tags: android

I've created a custom account and a sync adapter for my application (PSM) and everything is OK
The problem comes when I added a custom preferences to my account

This is my an image of my account
[image: pit]

This is my account with custom settings category
[image: tyt]

When I click this account settings (Settings crashes ), and I can't get stack trace or anything

Images on these links, reputation thing 
[image: wef3]

here is my code snippet for preference.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="General Settings" >
        <PreferenceScreen
            android:key="account_settings"
            android:title="@string/pref_account_settings_title"
            android:summary="@string/pref_account_settings_summary">
            <intent 
                android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:targetPackage="com.example.activities"
                android:targetClass="com.example.activities.OldPSMPreferences" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is a snippet for AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.activities.OldPSMPreferences">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The authenticator.xml snippet

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="com.certifix.psm.account"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/ACCOUNT_NAME"
    android:accountPreferences="@xml/preference"/>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: ... and what logcat said?

Comment: nothing I can't get anything out of it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it
The problem at preferences.xml:
I've changed it into that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="General Settings" />
        <PreferenceScreen
            android:key="account_settings"
            android:title="@string/pref_account_settings_title"
            android:summary="@string/pref_account_settings_summary">
            <intent 
                android:targetPackage="com.example.psm"
                android:targetClass="com.example.psm.activities.OldPSMPreferences"
                />
        </PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Preference Category can't contain a preference screen.
Also I've to remove the parent useless preference screen

Thanks for trying to help me guys :)